# What is the origin of radioactivity that appears *sometimes* in rivers close to a nuclear plant?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

What is the origin of radioactivity that appears *sometimes* in rivers close to a nuclear plant? (due to nuclear plant activity) ?

In particular, is it due to primary circuit that would contaminate the tertiary circuit ?

Or is it due to nuclear waste that is sent on purpose to the river once its radioactivity is lower to the maximum threshold authorized by authorities ?

Comment: Please indicate in the question: which nuclear plant and which river and what radioactivity was measured.

Comment: My question is *without any example* : it is a *general* question : this is something usual that in river close to a nuclear plant, there is a bit more radioactivity than in rivers not close to a nuclear plant.

Comment: If it is in fact usual then you should be able to find an example. I think you are wrong in general. Levels of radioactivity near many nuclear power plants are lower than levels of radioactivity near coal power plants. A specific example would be more convincing. Furthermore you specified in your question that it is due to the power plant activity. So different power plant designs will have different possibilities.

Comment: I'm not saying that there is radioactivity in general : I'm looking for the *reason* of radioactivity in a river *in the case* where the nuclear plant is the reason : what is the exact reason : contamination from primary circuit to the tertiary circuit, waste sent to river, etc. I search for the exact reason *in the case* where the nuclear plant is the "global reason".

Comment: You still need to identify a specific plant. Different nuclear power plants are constructed completely differently. And differently constructed plants will have different possible failure modes. Your question is incomplete as is and you show no willingness to clarify. I have no choice but to vote to close. Hopefully you will be more willing to clarify your question in the future instead of wasting time defending an unclear question.

Comment: @Dale : sorry for your point of view. There are plenty of nuclear plants. In very rare cases, there is more radioactivity in the river than usual, and I was wondering of the *general* reason, not a specific reason for a given example. You may understand the concept of "generality/theory" which is different to "specific example". ok, please do your vote if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for providing the link to the [article](https://www.rfi.fr/en/20190619-radioactivity-levels-abnormally-high-france-loire-river-monitor-nuclear-power-contamination), which discusses measured tritium contamination in a French river.

Tritium can come from many different places/reactions, but in a PWR it is usually from boron absorption and decay in the primary loop.  Tritium is a very light nuclei and is very difficult to contain, it can even pass through steel piping.  The tritium is produced in the primary loop, but then it can go to cleanup loops and escape into the environment, which is usually groundwater.  From groundwater, it can get to the river.

Tritium is very difficult to contain, but it is also very benign biologically (meaning no measured adverse affects).  The body quickly rejects tritium, so it doesn't stay in the body long enough to do much damage.  It is interesting that the news article had a quote a "'flagrant' lack of data on the carcinogenic effects of tritium".  The reason for the lack of data is that it is very difficult to show that tritium has a carcinogenic effect!

Since there is not much data showing the carcinogenic effect of tritium, international standards vary considerably.  The article implies that the environmental limits in France are 100 Bq/L, which means you can measure 100 tritium decays in a liter of water.  In the US, the limit is 740 Bq/L  (20,000 picoCuries per liter).  The values measured were 310 Bq/L.

Additional information about tritium can be found on the [NRC website](https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/fact-sheets/tritium-radiation-fs.html).

In summary, tritium is very hard to contain, easy to measure, and relatively harmless.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NuclearFission for your patience and your useful explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague.  There could be numerous reasons.

1. Natural occurring
2. Minor releases from the reactor

Very little radioactive material can be transferred from the primary to the tertiary loops.  They are designed to not allow material transfer.

Also the steam used to turn turbines is not released into rivers.  The steam that has passed through the turbines will be released into the air as steam after it passes through a cooling tower or condensers.

Comment: Thank you. My question is mainly : *in the case where there is a bit of radioactivity in the river*, is it mainly due to the primary circuit that would contaminate the tertiary circuit (=not on purpose), or is it mainly due to nuclear waste that is sent (=on purpose) to the river once its radioactivity is lower to the maximum threshold authorized by authorities ?

Comment: Sorry but only a specified example of such contamination occurring can merit a decent, specific answer. Do you have a specific incident in mind?

Comment: no : I don't have any example. if we google, we see that sometimes, there is a bit more radioactivity in river close to a nuclear plant. I was looking for the reason, in particular if it is due to contamination of tertiary circuit from primary circuit *or* if this is due to recycling the *nuclear waste*. There are the only possible reasons that come to my mind, but I don't know which one could be dominant.

Comment: *example* : https://www.rfi.fr/en/20190619-radioactivity-levels-abnormally-high-france-loire-river-monitor-nuclear-power-contamination

Comment: Rick, steam that passes through turbines will be low pressure steam that is condensed with cooling water so it can be pumped back to a heat exchanger to be turned back into high pressure steam.  The steam coming out of the cooling tower is evaporated cooling water.

Comment: "minor releases," Sounds like _intentional_ releases, but don't forget that there are also _leaks._ The Vermont Yankee power station was notorious for leaking large amounts of tritium, and traces of fission products from the primary loop into the local groundwater and river in 2010. One leak eventually was found, but there may have been at least one other. Only the one was found however, before they shut the plant down for good in 2014.

Comment: Re, what @DavidWhite said, The same is true for coal-fired and oil-fired power stations. You don't want an "open cycle" in a big thermal power station. The steam passing through the turbines is pure, de-ionized water. Any new water that gets added (as it must be from time to time because of occasional leaks and releases) potentially carries minerals that will be deposited as _[boiler scale](https://www.lenntech.com/applications/process/boiler/scaling.htm)_ inside the system, and scale buildup inevitably leads to costly maintenance shutdowns.